# How to make api call in useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

Here's a class component I'd like to refactor to a functional component using `useReducer`

```
export default class FootballMatchesData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedYear: null,
      matchData: [],
      firstCall: false
    };
  }

  chooseYear = (year) => (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedYear: year
    })
    axios.get(`https://website?property=${year}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ matchData: res.data, firstCall: true })
      })
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm stuck at defining the 'CHOOSE_YEAR' case of my reducer.
How would I define that case so that it:

1. updates `selectedYear`
2. makes an api call to `https://website?property=${year}`, then populates `matchData`
3. updates `firstCall`

Here is my current refactor. https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-pare-um66h?file=/src/FootballMatches.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem unfamiliar with the reducer pattern. Reducers are pure functions taking a state object and action to apply to that state, and returns the next state object. There are ***zero*** side-effects in reducer functions.

Use an `useEffect` hook to fetch the data when `year` updates in state. You may not want to *also* use anchor tags for the year list options since clicking that will likely try to navigate or reload the app/page.

```
const initialState = {
  selectedYear: null,
  competitions: [],
  firstCall: false
};

const footballReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHOOSE_YEAR":
      return {
        selectedYear: action.year, // <-- save year payload
        firstCall: true
      };

    case "FETCH_BY_YEAR_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state, // <-- copy existing state
        competitions: action.competitions // <-- save competitions payload
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const FootballMatches = () => {
  const [state, dispatchFootball] = useReducer(footballReducer, initialState);

  const yearChooseHandler = (year) => {
    dispatchFootball({ type: "CHOOSE_YEAR", year });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.year) { // <-- ensure year value is truthy since null on initial render
      axios.get(`https://website?property=${state.year}`).then((res) => { // <-- access state.year for URL
        dispatchFootball({
          type: "FETCH_BY_YEAR_SUCCESS",
          competitions: res.data,
          firstCall: true
        });
      }
    });
  }, [state.year]); // <-- year dependency

  let years = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017];
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Select Year</div>
      <ul>
        {years.map((year, idx) => {
          return (
            <li
              onClick={() => yearChooseHandler(year)} // <-- fix callback so it isn't invoked immediately and cause infinite render looping
              key={idx}
            >
              {year}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's a very helpful reply. I really appreciate the comments in the code as well. Thank you!

Comment: Can I make API request  in `yearChooseHandler` method right after dispatchFootball call? Or it is a bad practice?

Comment: @Shahin I don't think making an API call after `dispatchFootball` in `yearChooseHandler` would be an issue. I would probably factor it into a function and call it versus placing all the fetching logic in the callback.

Comment: How? AFAIK, `useReducer` hook does not offer callback functionality like `useState` does, which we could make API call in callback function. Can you please show example with `useReducer`?

Comment: @Shahin Oh, sorry, I thought you meant literally on the next line *after* calling `dispatchFootball({ type: "CHOOSE_YEAR", year });`. If I know understand your question you are looking for something like a class-based component's `this.setState` callback that is called *after* the state is updated. In functional components hooks don't do this, but the common pattern is to use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state you want the effect to be run after. If this is something you do often you could create a custom `useReducerWithCallback` hook.

Comment: Yes, you were right, I meant  literally on the next line after calling `dispatchFootball({ type: "CHOOSE_YEAR", year });` Please checkout  [this] (https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-bash-b4i07?file=/src/App.js) codesandbox. I put comments on top of the file.

Comment: @Shahin Ah, ok, thanks for clarifying. Yeah, between the two, your option one with `useEffect` with dependency on the `state.country` is IMHO the better of the two. It follows from the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and allows `onCountrySelect` to just be responsible for updating the country in state, and the second `useEffect`'s callback is responsible for fetching and updating `state.cities` in response.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!